# Workflow 4.0 and serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, workflow-foundation-4

I have an activity:

```
public sealed class MyStupidActivity<T> : NativeActivity<T>
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the activity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

it has a designer, and a custom serializer

```
     [DesignerSerializer(typeof(StupidActivityDesignerSerializer), typeof(WorkflowMarkupSerializer))]
     [Designer(typeof(StupidActivityDesigner))]
     public sealed class MyStupidActivity<T> : NativeActivity<T>
```

but it never seems to invoke my serializer methods. what is required? i've put breakpoints on the constructor / before / afterserialize methods, and nothing.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Gonna guess the ActivityXamlServices does not respect this attribute.  Why do you want to control how your Activity is serialized?  (a bit of Reflector work and I see it definitely does not; the DSA was respected by WF3, which is why you can find it when searching for custom activity designer serializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Will mentioned the DesignerSerializerAttribute was used in WF3 but is no longer used in WF4. I am not aware of any way to control the XAML generation.